# Is it necessary to define runtime/"run time" in m3u playlist file or is there a way around it?

Tags: m3u, m3u8

E.g. in the m3u file below, the running times are listed as **419**, **260** and **255**.

---

```
 #EXTM3U
 #EXTINF:419,Alice In Chains - Rotten Apple
 Alice In Chains_Jar Of Flies_01_Rotten Apple.mp3
 #EXTINF:260,Alice In Chains - Nutshell
 Alice In Chains_Jar Of Flies_02_Nutshell.mp3
 #EXTINF:255,Alice In Chains - I Stay Away
```

---

- **Is it possible to write an m3u file without these properties?**

  - Or just include some kind of **default**?

    - Are there **repercussions**?

Comment: Since you seem to have copied that example straight from [the Wikipedia page on the M3U playlist format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), you could’ve _read_ there yourself also that only some kind of path or URL is required, and everything else are optional extras …

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for m3u. The time is optional.  You can enter just "1" for time if you want.  Furthermore, the entire line is optional:

```
#EXTINF:419,Alice In Chains - Rotten Apple
 Alice In Chains_Jar Of Flies_01_Rotten Apple.mp3
```

Could be replaced with:

```
 Alice In Chains_Jar Of Flies_01_Rotten Apple.mp3
```

The `#EXTINF`: tag is for the extended format.  As a matter of fact it is not even understood by some players and will cause the entire playlist to appear as empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends a lot on what is going to read the playlist.

The most basic m3u file just contains the list of files (or URLs) without any of the '#' lines. In this format the player will have to read the files if it wants to know their duration. This could be slow especially for URLs.